# Merging two arrays with array1 as key and array2 as value

Tags: ecmascript-6

```js
const dataParams = [];  
let data={
         A:'5',
         B:'6',
         C:'7',
         D:'8'
       }
for(let d in data){
 dataParams.push(d + '=' + data[d]);  
}
console.log(dataParams)
```

I have an object as below i just need to print it as an array like
["A=5", "B=6", "C=7", "D=8"]

The Below code is working please see the console.

But i have read about the keys and values method in JS

Object.keys(data) // [A,B,C,D]
Object.values(data) // ['5','6','7','8']

Is there any way that i can get the  same output with the help of using keys and values method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `object#entries` with `array#map`

```js
let data={A:'5',B:'6',C:'7', D:'8'},
  result = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`);
  console.log(result);
```

You can also use `Object.keys()`

```js
let data={A:'5',B:'6',C:'7', D:'8'},
      result = Object.keys(data).map(k => `${k}=${data[k]}`);
      console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank for the quick response !!:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` with `Object.keys`

```js
var data = {
  a:1,
  b:2,
  c:3,
  d:4
}

var list = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(keyValueList, prop){
  keyValueList.push(prop + '=' + data[prop])
  return keyValueList;
}, []);

console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using both key and value, `Object.entries` is probably best for you:

```
const dataParams = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`);
```